# Display the estimote beacons on android app

Tags: android

I am building a very simple indoor location app using estimote beacons. I have the distance (estimated of course) and RSSI from the three beacons. What I want to achieve is to display the three beacons on my app (for the user) and his own location relative to them. I am assuming conditions to be ideal as of now. I am thinking of using trilateration to achieve this. Could some one please guide me?

TIA :)

Comment: You could have a look at [what has been discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trilateration) and edit your question if there's some more specific problem that you need help with.

Comment: One of the older discussions point to a [more elaborate look at tri/multilateration](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40660/trilateration-algorithm-for-n-amount-of-points).